# Error when using aws wafv2 create-web-acl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using version 2.0.50 of the AWS cli on Linux, and trying to create a v2 AWS WAF. Running the command aws wafv2 create-web-acl --cli-input-json file://waf.json results in the following response:

An error occurred (WAFInvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateWebACL operation: Error reason: Your statement has multiple values set for a field that requires exactly one value., field: RULE, parameter: Rule

Can somebody identify what is wrong with the following JSON, or confirm that they are seeing the same issue?

```
{
    "DefaultAction": {
        "Allow": {}
    },
    "Name": "test-web-acl",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Name": "rule-one",
            "Priority": 1,
            "Statement": {
                "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
                    "Name": "AWSManagedRulesUnixRuleSet",
                    "VendorName": "AWS"
                }
            },
            "VisibilityConfig": {
                "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
                "MetricName": "rule-one-metric",
                "SampledRequestsEnabled": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "Scope": "REGIONAL",
    "VisibilityConfig": {
        "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
        "MetricName": "test-web-acl-metric",
        "SampledRequestsEnabled": false
    }
}
```

I can't see what is incorrect about the JSON according to the syntax described here [CreateWebACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_CreateWebACL.html)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the OverrideAction attribute is missing from the Rule object.  When adding "OverrideAction":{"None":{}} to the Rule object, then the ACL was created.  The error message is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
# resources.tf
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "ip_whitelist" {
  name               = var.waf_name
  scope              = var.waf_scope
  ip_address_version = var.waf_ip_address_version
  addresses          = [var.waf_addresses]
}


resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "web_acl" {
  name        = var.waf_web_acl_name
  description = var.waf_description
  scope       = var.waf_scope

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }
  
  # ipsets
  rule {
    name     = var.waf_name
    priority = 0
    action {
      allow {}
    }
    statement {
      ip_set_reference_statement {
        arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.ip_whitelist.arn
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = var.waf_name
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = var.waf_name
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.rules
    content {
      name     = rule.value.name
      priority = rule.value.priority

      override_action {
        none {}
      }

      statement {
        managed_rule_group_statement {
          name        = rule.value.managed_rule_group_statement_name
          vendor_name = rule.value.managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name
        }
      }

      visibility_config {
        cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
        metric_name                = rule.value.metric_name
        sampled_requests_enabled   = true
      }
    }
  }
} 

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "waf_alb" {
  resource_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.web_acl.arn

}

# variables.tf
# waf ipset name
variable "waf_name" {
  type = string
  default = "ip-whitelist"
}

variable "waf_scope" {
  type = string
  default = "REGIONAL"
}
variable "waf_ip_address_version" {
  default = "IPV4"
  type=string
}
variable "waf_addresses" {
  default = "your-ip/32" 
  type = string
}

# waf details
variable "waf_web_acl_name" {
  type=string
  default = "waf-rules"
}

variable "waf_description" {
  type=string
  default = "waf rules"
}
# waf multiple rules
variable "rules" {
  type = list(any)
  default = [
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 1
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesPHPRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 2
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesPHPRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 3
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
      priority                                 = 4
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 5
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesUnixRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 6
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesUnixRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    },
    {
      name                                     = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
      priority                                 = 7
      managed_rule_group_statement_name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
      managed_rule_group_statement_vendor_name = "AWS"
      metric_name                              = "foo_name"
    }
  ]
}
```